# How to make activity the filter sort by price after adding new element to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, oop, dom, ecmascript-6

When you click on `<th> Price: </ th>`, the goods are sorted by price, the method: `sortProductsByPrice (sortOrder)` in the order of the increase. Sorting works, but it's necessary that after the sorting is activated, that is, there was a click on `<th> Price: </ th>`, then the new goods were already added sorted by price, and not click again on `<th> Price: </ th>` to sort them out.

I'm trying to do this in the method: `addProduct(newProduct)` I try to implement it like this:

```
  //method for adding a product
addProduct(newProduct) {
    if (this.sortProductsByPrice === true) {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
        this.sortProductsByPrice(Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC);
    }else  {
        this.products.push(newProduct);
    }
}
```

**But the code does not work as I described above**

```js
 class Product {
    constructor(name, count, price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
// Сlass where products are recorded
 class Shop {
    constructor() {
        this.products = [];
        this.formAdd = document.forms[0];
        this.inputsAdd = this.formAdd.elements;
        this.buttAdd = this.formAdd.elements[3];
        this.formDelete = document.forms[1];
        this.nameDelete = this.formDelete.elements[0];
        this.buttDelete = this.formDelete.elements[1];

    }

    //method for adding a product
    addProduct(newProduct) {
        if (this.sortProductsByPrice === true) {
            this.products.push(newProduct);
            this.sortProductsByPrice(Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC);
        }else  {
            this.products.push(newProduct);
        }
    }

    //method for remove product by name
    deleteProductByName(productName) {
        let i = this.products.length;
        while (i--) {
            if (productName === this.products[i].name) {
                this.products.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    //method for sorting the product at its price
    sortProductsByPrice(sortOrder) {
        const sorted = this.products.sort((a, b) => {
            return a.price > b.price ? sortOrder : -sortOrder;
        });
        this.products = sorted;
    }

    // method to draw the table with product property (
    // name, count, price)
    show() {

        const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#shop .data");
        for (let i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            const e = rows.item(i);
            e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
        }
        const table = document.getElementById("shop");
        const tFoot = table.querySelector('tfoot');
        if (tFoot) tFoot.remove();

        for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length; i++) {
            //create table
            table.innerHTML += `<tbody><tr class="data"><td>${this.products[i].name}</td>
    <td>${this.products[i].price}</td>
    <td>${this.products[i].count}</td></tr></tbody>`;
        }
    }

    OperationsWithProducts() {
        // add new product by click
        this.buttAdd.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (this.inputsAdd[0].value === "" || this.inputsAdd[1].value === "" || this.inputsAdd[2].value === "") {
                alert("fill all fields");
            } else {
                this.addProduct(new Product(this.inputsAdd[0].value, parseInt(this.inputsAdd[2].value),
                    parseInt(this.inputsAdd[1].value)));
                this.show();
                this.inputsAdd[0].value = "";
                this.inputsAdd[1].value = "";
                this.inputsAdd[2].value = "";
            }
        }, false);
        // delete product by name after click
        this.buttDelete.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (this.nameDelete.value === "") {
                alert("write a name of product what you want to delete");
            } else {
                this.deleteProductByName(this.nameDelete.value);
                this.show();
                this.nameDelete.value = "";
            }

        }, false);
        //filter products by price
        document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            let elem = e.target;
            if (elem.id === "filter") {
                this.sortProductsByPrice(Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC);
                this.show();
            }
        }, false);
        console.log(this.products);
    }
}

Product.SORT_ORDER_ASC = 1;
let shop = new Shop();
shop.addProduct(new Product("product", 1, 2000));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product1", 2, 500));
shop.addProduct(new Product("product2", 3, 1000));
shop.show();
shop.OperationsWithProducts();
```

```html
<div class="Shop">
    <div class="add-product">
        <h1>Add product</h1>
        <form id="addForm">
            <label for="name" >Name of product</label>
            <input type="text"  id="name" class="input-product">
            <label for="price">Price of product</label>
            <input type="number"  id="price" class="input-product">
            <label for="count">Count of product</label>
            <input type="number"  id="count" class="input-product">
            <button id="add" type="button">Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="product-table">
        <h2>Products</h2>
        <form id="delete-form">
            <label for="name-delete">Delete product by name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name-delete" class="input-delete">
            <button id="delete" type="button">Delete</button>
        </form>
        <table id="shop">
            <tr>
                <th>Name:</th>
                <th id="filter">Price:</th>
                <th>Count:</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your equality check here: `if (this.sortProductsByPrice === true) {` This if statement never resolves to true because `this.sortProductsByPrice` is not a boolean.

I was able to get the code to work by adding a new variable on the instance inside the constructor: `this.sortByPrice = false;`, setting it to true inside of `if (elem.id === "filter")` `this.sortByPrice = true;` (because once price is clicked, subsequent product additions should be auto-sorted, if I understand you question correctly) and changing the `if (this.sortProductsByPrice === true) {` statement to `if (this.sortByPrice === true) {`

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
this.sortProductsByPrice === true
```

Will not help you in determining if the products were already sorted, since it returns the content of the function. 
Inside `sortProductsByPrice` function, you can add a line to set a parameter when the sorting is activated. By the code you provided I can't tell where you'd like to clear the sorting filter.
An example:

```
sortProductsByPrice(foo) {
  // sort your products
  // ...

  // state that your products were sorted
  this.productsAreSorted = true;
}

// then when adding:
addProduct(newProduct) {
    this.products.push(newProduct); // no need to repeat this line two times

    if (this.productsAreSorted) {
        this.sortProductsByPrice(foo);
    }
}

// Somewhere you'd likely want to clear the filter

// You may also want to sort by name, number, count and other <td>
// instead of saving a true/false,save sort type as string

fooBarSort(fooBar){
  this.sortType = fooBar;
  this.sortOrder = this.sortOrder == 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
  // do the sorting
}
```

Comment: actually it always evaluates to `false` since it is a strict comparison (*type must match and it will not in this case since once is a Function and the other a boolean*)

Comment: Noobie mistake! Thanks Gabriele, I'm editing my answer right now